# Minkowski Space and the Expansion of the Universe

Tags: special-relativity, space-expansion, causality

I was watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hj8ZCQtrpU) about Minkowski space.  It stated that no past event, outside of the light cone in space can be a cause of an action inside the light cone.  Is this due to the expansion of the universe? or is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

"the light cone in space" is a somewhat irritating formulation. I am not sure whether this is a part of your problem, but keep in mind that the light cone is not a region in 3-space but in four dimensional space-time. The past light cone of a point (x,t) (position in 3-space + time) consists out of all points in space-time from which a light signal could possibly reach (x,t). If something is outside this region then it cannot affect anything within the light cone as any signal with which it could do so would have to be transferred with a speed greater than the speed of light. This has nothing to do with the expansion of the universe after all the expansion of the universe is covered by general relativity and we are now only talking about special relativity.

Comment: So is Minkowski space something that is formulistic - not based on the macro scale but on the particle scale?

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: I guess, I am trying to determine when you would describe something using Minkowski space. I would love a real world example.  (I am not a student or scientist, so it is kind of confusing.)

Comment: Ah ok, so Minkowski space is uncurved space-time so it is sufficient to describe physics in which gravity is not important. As soon as gravity becomes relevant you need more complicated space-times which are described by general relativity.

Comment: Thank you...  So would you say it is time dependent?